# Acer Aspire 5349-2592 touchpad scrollbar not working - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, scrollbar

I have installed a new hard drive, updated the entire computer and installed Windows 10 Pro.

Now that the computer is working up to pare, there seems to be an issue getting the scrollbar working again... Help?

Comment: Did you install the [touchpad](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/MY/content/support-product/3904?b=1) driver?

Comment: Thankfully didn't need to. I didn't understand the way these settings are displayed, but I was able to find where I needed to be and was corrected the issue.

Comment: @Victoria Please make an answer explaining how you solved this issue, so other people don't waste their time on an already fixed problem

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your case, you do not have the appropriate software installed. Have a look at your manufacturer’s [Driver List](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/MY/content/support-product/3904?b=1)